# (Java) how do I use checkbox generated with a for

Tags: java, swing

I have a Problem, I generate some checkbox with a for and i need to use them but don´t know how they are named to call them.

```
for(disponibility prov: dis){

JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox();

check.setBounds(30,156,97,33);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an array list type of structure to store all your checkboxes. Access them using an index later. If you want to name them based on some property of `disponibility`, you can use a map to store the checkboxes.

```
List<JCheckBox> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(disponibility prov: dis){    
   JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox();    
   check.setBounds(30,156,97,33);
   list.add(check);
}
//Later access nth checkbox
list.get(n).setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Just as a side note, there are many *container* like datastructures, summarized under the class `Collection`. For example there are different implementations of `Set` like `HashSet` or `TreeSet` and there are `Map` like `HashMap` and also `List` like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` and multiple others. They differ in efficiency for different usages.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't realize that.